# Brownian motion reflected on a sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, boundary-value-problem

Consider a standard Wiener process (in 3 dimensions) $(W_t)_{t>0}$, such that $W_0 = x_0 \neq 0$. I am trying to determine the transition density of $(W_t)$ reflected on a sphere of radius $a < \|x_0\|$ centered at $0$.

I considered that the laplacian is a self-adjoint operator, so I can write the Fokker Planck equation to obtain the density function:

$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t p = \Delta p\\
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} p(t,x) = \delta(x-x_0)\\
\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}\Big|_{r=a}  = 0 
\end{cases}
$$

Is there any way I can obtain a closed form for $p$?

Instead of starting from $x_0$, I could start from a distribution that has spherical symmetry and transform it to 1D equation, but I'd prefer to have a closed form when starting from a point.

Comment: How do you define the process reflected on the sphere? There seems to be several plausible options to do that.

Comment: @Did Normal reflection à la Lions. That's how I've obtained the boundary condition. Locally, a circle is a plane so Tanaka formula that gives the Neumann condition. Maybe I didn't understand your question. What types other types of reflection could be possible in this case?